# How can I do a multi level parent-child sort using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sorting

How can I do a multi-level parent-child sort using Linq if I have a table structure like the one below:

```
[Table: Sections]  
Id   Seq   Name        ParentSectionId  
1    1     TOP         NULL  
2    1     AAAA        1  
3    2     SSSS        1
4    3     DDDD        1  
5    1     SectionA1   2
6    2     SectionA2   2  
7    1     SectionS1   3  
8    3     ASummary    2
```

Expected sort result:

```
TOP  
  AAAA  
    SectionA1  
    SectionA2  
    ASummary  
  SSSS  
    SectionS1  
  DDDD
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performing a hierarchical search/sort with an adjacency list is not an easy thing to do, especially in Linq.

Rather than write a big block of code here to do this, I will refer you to somebody else who has already done it:

[Linq AsHierarchy() Extension Method](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET23)

This will convert the adjacency list into an actual tree structure, which is then easy to display/search/sort in a hierarchical fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it. It is untested, so let me know:

```
from section in db.Sections
group section by section.ParentSectionId into childGroup
orderby childGroup.Key
from childSection in childGroup.OrderBy(child => child.Seq)
select childSection
```

Comment: This will only work if the hierarchy is already in sorted order by ID, which is unlikely.  Picture [1] and [5] at the root, with respective children [8] and [2]; the children of [2] will appear before the children of [8], which is wrong.

Comment: Seems to put SectionS1 at the very end of the list and ASummary second to last.

Answer (score 0):

I bet

```
from section in db.Sections
where section.sec=0
orderby section.Name
```

would be enough and Linq will do the rest
only you have to specify state LoadWith statement